# Information about ε-greedy algorithms

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, artificial-intelligence, greedy-algorithms

I'm working on a [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5672586&newsearch=true&queryText=reinforcement%20learning%20first%20person%20shooter) that uses ε-greedy algorithms for choosing episodes of a sarsa q-learning algorithms. I searched for algorithm but couldn't get so much. Can you please give me the algorithms and a little explanations about it?

Comment: This question asks to list a potentially large body of work. Community votes, please: is this too broad?

Comment: @Raphael what you mean? what is the problem?

Comment: @mtk99 "Working on", not "working with". It would be unusual to share a link to a paper that's not complete yet.

Comment: @DavidRicherby On the other hand, it is also unusual to ask strangers on the internet to explain the topic of the paper you are writing to you.

Comment: Can you share a link to the paper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ε-greedy is just a way to promote exploration in Reinforcement Learning. I would not classify SARSA or Q-Learning as ε-greedy algorithms.

The latter are very common reinforcement learning algorithms and you can definitely can find lots of material about them.

I would suggest to have a look at this classic book (the draft for the second edition is available for free)

https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/the-book.html

Another shorter and excellent resource is (have a look at chapter 21):

*Russell SJ, Norvig P, Davis E. Artificial intelligence: a modern approach. Upper Saddle River, NJ: Prentice Hall; 2010.*

EDIT:

The paper you posted is using SARSA(λ), it is not the same as SARSA. You will need to go through a few Sutton chapters for that to make sense. You won't find it in Russell.

The link to SARSA(λ) in Sutton (1998) HTML version is here: webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node77.html

However, I think you will need to read at least chapter 6 before jumping into eligibility traces

Comment: i think the paper meant sarsa from ε-greedy algorithm but im looking for a trace algorithm that how it really works

Comment: This is the link to SARSA($\lambda$) in Sutton (1998) HTML version: https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node77.html , however I think you will need to read at least chapter 6 before jumping into eligibility traces

Comment: can you give just a simple trace example or explanation? the book just shows the algorithm. i cant understand it well.